# Can I call methods of "aliased" types in single-case discriminated unions?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I read in the excellent `F# for Fun and Profit` that I could use single-case discriminated unions for, among other things, get type safety. So I tried to do that. But I quickly discovered that I could not call the methods of the type that was (sort of) aliased or viewed by the DU.

Here is an example:

```
type MyList = MyList of List<int>
let list' = [1; 2; 3]
printfn "The list length is %i" list'.Length
let myList = MyList([1; 2; 3])
// The list length is 3
// type MyList = | MyList of List<int>
// val list' : int list = [1; 2; 3]
// val myList : MyList = MyList [1; 2; 3]
```

So far so good. Then I tried

```
myList.Length
// Program.fs(12,8): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Length' is not defined.
```

Is there a simple way of accessing the methods of the "aliased" or "viewed" type when one is using a single-case DU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what you call an "alias". You've declared a whole new type, which wraps a list inside it. Your type is not just another name for list, it's a wrapper.

If you want to declare a true alias, you should use syntax `type A = B`, for example:

```
type MyList = List<int> 
let myList : MyList = [1; 2; 3]
printf "Length is %d" myList.Length
```

With such alias, `MyList` will be 100% substitutable for `List<int>` and vice versa. This is what is usually meant by "alias". Different name for the same thing.

A wrapper, on the other hand, will give you extra type safety: the compiler will catch if you try to use a naked `List<int>` where `MyList` is expected. This is how such wrappers are usually used. But this extra protection comes with a price: you can't just use `MyList` as if it was a list. Because that would kill the whole idea. Can't have it both ways.

#### Q: wait, do you mean to say I have to reimplement all the list functionality just to get this wrapper?

Well, no. If you move past methods and towards functions, you can make this wrapping/unwrapping generic by providing a `map`:

```
type MyList = MyList of List<int>
   with static member map f (MyList l) = f l

let myList = MyList [ 1; 2; 3 ]
let len = MyList.map List.length myList
```

If you find yourself using a specific function a lot, you can even give it its own name:

```
let myLen = MyList.map List.length
let len = myLen myList
```

[Here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/) is another article from Mr. Wlaschin on the subject.

Also note: this is yet another way in which methods are inferior to functions. One would generally do well to avoid methods when possible.

Comment: Fair enough. But I thought there might be some syntactic sugar that allowed me to use `myList` just as if it was a list. Something like `myList$.Length`. That would have been a nice feature for `F#`, although I have no idea of how hard it would be to implement it.

Comment: Super! I was already trying my hand on a solution like yours, but I did not think of using a static function. My solution had an infix operator:
`let (>.<) f (MyList l) = f l`

`List.length >.< myList`

Comment: I am a beginner with F# but, cautiously given my level of ignorance, I am getting more and more inclined to agree that methods are inferior to functions. Still, writing the name of an instance followed by a dot and getting all the methods that apply is a nice feature. I wonder if Intellisense could be extended to do something similar for the functions that have the object as an argument. Something like `myList$` would generate a pop-up with all the relevant `List.` functions. If one of them (say, `length`) is chosen then the code on the screen would already show `List.length myList`.

Comment: Feel free to submit a suggestion on [UserVoice](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language).

Answer (score 3):

Using a single-case discriminated union creates a new type - both in the technical and in the logical sense - and it also hides the implementation details of the type.

If you are defining a new type (be it by wrapping some other type), there is no reason why operations that work on the wrapped type `list<int>` should also work on type `MyList` (or why it should be easy to make them work on `MyList`), because you can decide to change the representation used in `MyList` at any point.

I think the example with lists is confusing - there is not much practical purpose in defining `MyList` (and a type alias might work better). But say you have something like `Password`:

```
type Password = Password of string
```

Now, you do not want to be able to run arbitrary `string` operations on a `Password` because that might break constraints that you expect to hold about passwords (e.g. that it contains a mix of lowercase and uppercase characters). If you could write `pass.Substring(0, 1)`, you would be creating invalid passwords!

So, I think it makes sense to use single-case DUs if you want to hide the underlying representation. Then you also want to define operations that work on type `Password` and do not use any of the operations for `string`. Type aliases are better if the types are really the same (and your alias has no additional constraints).

Comment: Yes, but ...

I might want to use a single case DU to obtain type safety, even if I want to have the same operations as those of the original type.

Comment: @Soldalma It's hard to comment without knowing a specific example - I think the idea is that using operations of the original type _often_ breaks the safety.

Comment: In my example above I used `List` to make it accessible to a wider audience. But what I really wanted to do was to use single-case DUs to differentiate between different kinds of `Deedle` DataFrames. I have DataFrames with different structures performing different roles in my program. I wanted to make sure that one could not pass the wrong kind of DataFrame to a function as an argument and hoped to use single-case DUs for that purpose. In all cases I want to have the full DataFrame functionality available.

Comment: @Soldalma I see - this explanation makes a lot more sense - I can see how this would be useful! The only alternative I can think of would be to use a more specific type of row/column keys to avoid this...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, which encapsulates what you do with the contents:

```
let length (MyList l) = l.Length
length myList
```